# Delayed expansion of composite variable in Bash

Tags: bash, logging, stack-trace, quoting, expansion

I'm defining a variable as a composition of other variables and some text, and I'm trying to get this variable to not expand its containing variables on the assigning. But I want it to expand when called later. That way I could reuse the same template to print different results as the inner variables keep changing. I'm truing to avoid `eval` as much as possible as I will be receiving some of the inner variables from third parties, and I do not know what to expect.

My use case, as below, is to have some "calling stack" so I can log all messages with the same format and keep a record of the script, function, and line of the logged message in some format like this: `script.sh:this_function:42`.

**My attempted solution**

`called.sh:`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_NAME="`basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`"
CURR_STACK="${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNCNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}"


echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNCNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}"
echo "${CURR_STACK}"
echo

function _func_1 {
    echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNCNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}"
    echo "${CURR_STACK}"
}
_func_1
```

So, I intend to get the same results while printing the `"${CURR_STACK}"` as when printing the previous line.

If there is some built-in or other clever way to log this 'call stack', by all means, let me know! I'll gladly wave my code good-bye, but I'd still like to know how to prevent the variables from expanding right away on the assigning of `CURR_STACK`, but still keep them able to expand further ahead.

Am I missing some `shopt`?

#### What I've tried:

**Case 1 (expanding on line 4):**

```sh
CURR_STACK="${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}"
```

```sh
CURR_STACK="`echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNCNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}"`"
```

```sh
CURR_STACK="`echo "\${SCRIPT_NAME}:\${FUNCNAME[0]}:\${LINENO[0]}"`"
```

```
called.sh::7              <------------------| These are control lines
called.sh::4  <---------------. .------------| With the results I expect to get.
                               X
called.sh:_func_1:12      <---´ `-------| Both indicate that the values expanded
called.sh::4  <-------------------------| on line 4 - when CURR_STACK was set.
```

**Case 2 (not expanding at all):**

```sh
CURR_STACK="\${SCRIPT_NAME}:\${FUNNAME[0]}:\${LINENO[0]}"
```

```sh
CURR_STACK=\${SCRIPT_NAME}:\${FUNCNAME[0]}:\${LINENO[0]}
```

```sh
CURR_STACK="`echo '${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNCNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}'`"
```

```
called.sh::7
${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}  <-------.----| No expansion at all!...
                                                  / 
called.sh::12                                    /
${SCRIPT_NAME}:${FUNNAME[0]}:${LINENO[0]}  <----´
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the [`PS4`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS4) Bash variable for this? See, for example, [this article](http://www.skybert.net/bash/debugging-bash-scripts-on-the-command-line/)

Comment: @BenjaminW. : 
Even if I don't end up using it here, that is one good trick I'll use for sure!
Let me check if I can use it for this use case.
Thanks!

Comment: actually this became too heavy on the amount of logs. But thanks for the trick - its really helpful for debugging and I'm not tacking it out of my PS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables are store plain inert text(*), not executable code; there isn't really any concept of delayed evaluation here. To make something that *does something* when used, create a function instead of a variable:

```
print_curr_stack() {
    echo "$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}"):${FUNCNAME[1]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
}
# ...
echo "We are now at $(print_curr_stack)"
# Or just run it directly:
print_curr_stack
```

Note: using `BASH_SOURCE[1]` and `FUNCNAME[1]` gets info about context the function was run from, rather than where it is in the function itself. But for some reason I'm not clear on, `BASH_LINENO[1]` gets the wrong info, and `BASH_LINENO[0]` is what you want.

You could also write it to allow the caller to specify additional text to print:

```
print_curr_stack() {
    echo "$@" "$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}"):${FUNCNAME[1]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
}
# ...
print_curr_stack "We are now at"
```

(* There's an exception to what I said about variables just contain inert text: some variables -- like `$LINENO`, `$RANDOM`, etc -- are handled specially by the shell itself. But you can't create new ones like this except by modifying the shell itself.)

Comment: Thanks a lot man!
When things are getting to tricky, the answer is usually this simpler!...

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with `eval`?

```sh
$ a=this; b=is; c=a; d=test;
$ e='echo "$a $b $c $d"';
$ eval $e;
this is a test

$ b='is NOT';  # modify one of the variables
$ eval $e;
this is NOT a test

$ f=$(eval $e);  # capture the value of the "eval" statement
$ echo $f;
this is NOT a test
```

Comment: ```eval``` was actually the only workarround I could find. But I'm trying to avoid it as much as possible as I do not know what script names or function names to expect.